# How to install both .js and .wasm files with the CMake target for emscripten?

Tags: cmake, emscripten

When building a C++/web-assembly project with CMake and emscripten, the [`install`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.13/command/install.html) command for the target only install the `.js` file and not the `.wasm` file.

```
install(TARGETS MyTarget RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/dist)
```

This will install the JS file only. I tried to add rules for `LIBRARY`, `RESOURCE`, `ARCHIVE`... but the Wasm is never copied. I could not find anything in the official doc.

I know it's easy to workaround using the `install(FILES ...` command to force the copy of the wasm, but is there no way to make the standard install work for both files? They are both needed as a target...

Comment: I have the same issue. Found a relevant [CMake bug](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/20745) but no solution yet.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of the workaround mentioned in the question for others like me who landed on this page after googling.

```
if (NOT EMSCRIPTEN)
    install(TARGETS MyTarget RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/dist)
else()
    install(FILES
        "$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:MyTarget>/MyTarget.js"
        "$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:MyTarget>/MyTarget.wasm"
        DESTINATION ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/dist)
endif()
```